# Javascript n-ary tree InOrder Function

Tags: javascript, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, inorder

I built a function to get values from a binary tree (InOrder) . Now I would like to modify that function so it would work with a n-ary tree.  I would appreciate your help.

```
function stringFromInOrder(tree, position) {
    if (!tree) {
        return "";  
    }else if(tree.value === ""){
            return false;
        }
    return  stringFromInOrder(tree.left) + tree.value + stringFromInOrder(tree.right) ;
}
```

Comment: There is no standard way of traversing a n-nary tree in order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stick with recursion:

```
function stringFromInOrder(tree, position) {
    if (!tree) {
        return "";  
    }else if(tree.value === ""){
            return false;
        }
    var s = 0;
    var i = 0
    while (i < tree.children.count)
    {
       s += stringFromInOrder(tree.children[i]);
       i++;
    }
    return  tree.value + s;
}
```

Comment: How would you implement the tree for this case? Create a n-ary tree? Thank you for your answer.